# What is the idiomatic way to make a get request using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, restsharp

I'm trying to make a GET request to a REST api which returns a JSON. This is what I have right now:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
var request = new RestRequest(CONTROLLER_PATH);
var response = await client.GetAsync<MyDtoClass[]>(request);
```

When this code executes, `response` is an array of `MyDtoClass` but the fields in each element of the array are `null`. If instead, I run this code (I removed the generic):

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
var request = new RestRequest(CONTROLLER_PATH);
var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
```

then `response` is a string represintation of the JSON that `BASE_URL + CONTROLLER_PATH` returns (nothing is null).

What is the idiomatic way to make a request to this REST api and convert the response into an array of `MyDtoClass`. Also, if anyone has suggestions for a library you think is better then RestSharp, please share.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us an example of the response. It's likely that it's not a plain array `[ ... ]` but a structured object `{ ... }`. But we need an example of the response to know for sure.

Comment: The response looks like this: `[{"category":"abc","status":"1"},{"category":"efg","status":"1"},{"category":"hij","status":"1"},{"category":"klm","status":"1"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `MyDtoClass` had fields instead of properties.